# Tilemill Shield placing not working

Tags: tilemill

I am trying to put road No in the shield with tilemill .mss. Here is the code I used.

```
#road {
    shield-file:  url(C:\wamp\www\shield.png);
    shield-name: [ROAD_NO];
    shield-face-name:"DejaVu Sans Bold";
    shield-size:10;
    shield-fill: white;
    shield-spacing:50;
    shield-line-spacing:5;
    shield-type: png;
        }
```

Its return two errors in the `shield-file` and `shield-name` fields.

What wrong I have done here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got It....

```
#road {
    shield-file:  url("C:\wamp\www\shield.png");
    shield-name: [ROAD_NO];
    shield-face-name:"DejaVu Sans Bold";
    shield-size:10;
    shield-fill: white;
    shield-spacing:50;
    shield-line-spacing:5;
    shield-type: png;
        }
```